# How to change button position in navigation bar

Tags: xcode, swift, button, position, navigationbar

So I've created a button in the navigation bar and set an image for it. This is how it looks like in storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M27y.jpg

So I've tried to set it right on the edge of the screen so there will be no gap between the image and the left side of the screen.

Here is the code I've used for it:

```
var screenWidth: CGFloat=0.0
    var screenHeight: CGFloat=0.0


    @IBOutlet weak var button1: 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIButton!        var screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    button1.frame.size = CGSizeMake(133, 44)
    button1.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: screenWidth-(button1.frame.width+20), y: 20)
    self.view.addSubview(button1)
```

And here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpS7i.jpg

Is this happening because I add my button straight to the TableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the button directly in the navbar. Also you can add constraints to your button using the xcode storyboard gui.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've placed button into the navbar. Or is it possible that's happening because I'm using TableViewController and if I try to put the button into the navbar I will always place it in the TableView?


Btw, if I change numbers in this row:


button1.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: screenWidth-(button1.frame.width+20), y: 20)


nothing happens. Is the source of this problem is the same?

Comment: Found a way out of this